# add extension module to groovy class

Tags: groovy, extension-modules

I am trying to create simple `extension module`.

I created `Main.groovy` file

```
class Item {
   String item
}

new Item().sayHello() // this method supposed to be extension
```

I compiled it (not ran).

I created `ItemExtension.groovy` class

```
class ItemExtension {
    def sayHello(Item self) {
        println "hello world"
    }
}
```

This is my `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` descriptor

```
moduleName=Item extension module
moduleVersion=1.0
extensionClasses=ItemExtension
```

I compiled `ItemExtension.groovy` using `groovyc` (I precompiled `Main.groovy` in order to get `Item` class)

```
groovyc ItemExtension.groovy
```

Compiled `ItemExtension.class` with `META-INF` I put into `.jar` file (renamed `.rar`). 
Its structure looks like this

```
META-INF\services\org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule
ItemExtension.class
```

I put `ItemExtension.jar` in the same folder as `Main.groovy` and compiled it again but with `cp` argument to add `jar`.

```
groovyc -cp ItemExtension.jar Main.groovy
```

But when I try to run it

```
groovy Main
```

I get this exception

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Item.sayHell
o() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Item.sayHello() is a
pplicable for argument types: () values: []
    at Main.run(Main.groovy:6)
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extension method has to be static to be recognized (because extension modules have to be stateless) and the `Item` class has to live into its own source file to be recognized (because otherwise it's an inner class of the script).

Here is a bash script that does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Create Item.groovy"
cat > 'Item.groovy' <<-EOF
class Item {
    String item
}
EOF

echo "Compile Item.groovy"
groovyc Item.groovy -d classes

echo "Create extension module class"
cat > 'ItemExtension.groovy' <<-EOF
class ItemExtension {
    static def sayHello(Item self) {
        println "hello world"
    }
}
EOF

echo "Create extension module descriptor"
mkdir -p classes/META-INF/services
cat > classes/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule <<-EOF
moduleName=Item extension module
moduleVersion=1.0
extensionClasses=ItemExtension
EOF

echo "Compile extension module"
groovyc -cp classes ItemExtension.groovy -d classes

echo "Creating script.groovy"
cat > 'script.groovy' <<-EOF
new Item().sayHello()
EOF

echo "Run script"
groovy -cp classes script.groovy
```

Comment: Oh I also missed the fact that you compiled using the extension jar (which is not necessary because your code is dynamic), but running *without* it. When you execute your script, the extension has to be on classpath:

    `groovyc Main.groovy` then `groovy -cp ItemExtension.jar Main.groovy`

Should work

Comment: still did not work. I guess I need to reread the documentation. Maybe overlooked something (like with static)

Comment: Edited my answer with a complete example.